# CSS for displaying Message

Tags: jquery, css

I have the ajax Loading Message which displays in the middle of the Page

```
#message {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I am just trying to make a fix to have a image around it so it looks separate and identifiable that something is loading

Comment: Share more code please.

Comment: i am using that in div id="message"></div>, that is only what i have and calling it in jquery ajax beforesend